# Remove blank categories in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I've written a function to create a plot with data that changes based on a filter

```
            library(tidyverse)                                               
               library(plotly)
one<- as.numeric(NA)
two<- 25
three<- 35
four<- 40
five<- 0
dat<- data.frame(one, two, three, four, five)

  get_plot <- function(x, a){
    data<- x[, a]                       
    p<- data %>%  
        pivot_longer(everything(), names_to="variable", values_to="value") %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = reorder(variable, value), y = value, fill = variable, text = paste0(value*100, "%"))) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge")+
        theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
              axis.text.x=element_blank(),
              axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
              axis.title.y=element_blank(),
              legend.position = "none")+
              coord_flip()
    ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text")) %>% config(displaylogo = FALSE,
                                                modeBarButtons = list(list("toImage")))
  }
  
get_plot(dat, a= c(1:5))
```

Depending on the filter sometimes I end up with a chart with categories that don't have values in them like in the image below. How do I exclude categories from appearing on the plot when there is no value for the category? **** edited to make a more simplified reprex****

[image: my bar plot with missing values for a filtered data set]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update, after thinking about it more this morning and doing more googling and trying things I figure out a solution. I inserted these select statements into the function and it gets me what I wanted!

```
p<- data %>%
select(where(~!any(is.na(.)))) %>%
select(where(~!any(.== 0))) %>%
```